# Can I define immutability through a copy function?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability

Is it safe to say that if for some type a copy function is an identity function, then the type is immutable?

Comment: If copy is only a *shallow* copy, then this definitely does *not* hold. So you need to make clear what you mean with "copying".

Comment: what is a shallow copy?

Comment: say you have a list of objects `[o1,o2,o3]`. If a "copy" would mean that you construct a new list `[o1,o2,o3]` (but without calling the copy function on `o1`, etc.) Then it is a shallow copy. The opposite is a *deep copy* where - given an object consists out of other objects - all these objects are copied as well.